# Returning a Built-In EditorTemplate as a PartialView in an Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, mvc-editor-templates

Is there a way to return a **built-in** editor template - not a custom editor template - as a PartialView in an action?

I'd like to do something like this:

```
return PartialView("Collection", person.Children);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to do this from a controller action. You could return a custom partial view:

```
return PartialView(person.Children);
```

that will invoke the editor template:

```
@model IEnumerable<Foo>
@Html.EditorForModel()
```